# Should I avoid using non-latin characters in my code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, character-encoding

I am Brazilian, I speak Portuguese, and in Portuguese there are many words with accents, there is a legacy in Brazil to avoid accents in programming, precisely because in the past accents gave much problems.

I'm a front end programmer, I tend to accentuate each word properly for a clearer reading of methods and variables.

I know that JavaScript, TypeScript and even CSS support accents (I know they support because browsers interpret the accented words I use). My question is if this would be considered bad practice. If in case I made an international web application, other countries could access my system normally or if the accents could break the application or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, you should avoid using accents.

### Long answer

Even if the language itself supports accents (I will refer to it as non-latin characters), it is usually good to avoid using them in code. All major browser today have Unicode support so it shouldn't be a problem for them to render code with non-latin characters, but it can be a problem when opening the files with code editors that doesn't recognize the character encoding. When that happens you might still get some problems with body text etc. but it won't break functionality.

It can usually also a good practice to write code in English (meaning you don't have to worry about non-latin characters all together), when the syntax of the language is in English. It makes it easier in a semantic purpose to read `if remember_me is True` than mixing two languages with each other.

If you ever plan on collaborate on projects with someone non-Brazilian/Portuguese, it might not be the case that everyone know the same language, and then English is the fallback/standard to write in. Also, if you are experienced in coding in English it won't be such a hassle to [come up with good names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Frn.jpg) for classes, methods etc.

### More reading

There is a some discussions and threads about this, I recommend reading from other sources:

- [Is it a good practice to code in English?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113936/is-it-a-good-practice-to-code-in-english?noredirect=1&lq=1) (*If you're only gonna read one, read this*)
- [Do people in non-English-speaking countries code in English?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english)
- [How do non-English speaking people write code when the syntax is in
  English?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-non-English-speaking-people-write-code-when-the-syntax-is-in-English-The-error-messages-are-also-in-English-How-would-they-know-what-those-mean-Some-errors-can-be-pretty-verbose)

### Trivia

There are also [Non-English based programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages) as well, even though if they aren't as widely used. Some examples in Portuguese are:

- [potigol](https://potigol.github.io/) - A functional programming language in Portuguese for beginners.
- [visualg](http://www.apoioinformatica.inf.br/produtos/visualg) - A language designed to teach programming, in Portuguese, based in Pascal.